# How to open and list contents of a zip file using windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, zip

In my svn repository, there are a lot of zip archives containing images. Recently we added a lot of new images. But some images are missing in some zip archives. How can I check whether an image is available inside a zip archive or not, from the command line?

I can check that a zip archive exists using this command:

```
svn info svn://ip/test/101.zip
```

Because my repository is large, my repo browser takes a long time to load. How can I check that an image is available or not inside a zip archive?
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Im pretty sure youd need to have the zip file in your working copy then you could unzip the file and compare whats there or depending on your utility you might be able to get a list of the contents of the zip for comparison, but either way i think youll need to have the file available in your local working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to open the zip file on the server, and search there for the contents. So you have to download the zip files to the client, list there the contents, and see if it matches. Depending on the zip command and the grep possibilities you have, this will be implemented differently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using third party tools for searching inside svn repositories. The most well-known search tool for svn is svn-search which is freely available on sourceforge. It can search inside .txt, .pdf, .doc, .zip and many other file formats. Use [this link](http://svn-search.sourceforge.net/) to get the tool